# GLSL : Accessing an array in a for-loop hinders performance

Tags: android, arrays, performance, libgdx, glsl

Okay, so I'm developing an android app for a game I'm making (with LibGDX). And I have a fragment shader and I noticed that I had ~41 FPS. I was playing around with the code to see where the problem was, and I saw that changing how I accessed an array from arrayName[i] to arrayName[0] increased the performance back to 60 FPS, even though the loop only iterated once in this specific instance.
Here's the code :

```
#version 300 es

precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

in vec2 vTexCoord0;

struct BlackHole {
    vec2 position;
    float radius;
    float deformRadius;
};

uniform vec2 screenSize;
uniform vec3 cameraPos;
uniform float cameraZoom;

uniform BlackHole blackHole[4];
uniform int count;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    vec2 pos = vTexCoord0;

    bool doSample = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        BlackHole hole = blackHole[i];  // <-------- blackHole is the array, and changing from [i] to [0]
        vec2 position = (hole.position - cameraPos.xy) / cameraZoom + screenSize*0.5;
        float radius = hole.radius / cameraZoom;
        float deformRadius = hole.deformRadius / cameraZoom;

        vec2 deltaPos = vec2(position.x - gl_FragCoord.x, position.y - gl_FragCoord.y);
        float dist = length(deltaPos);

        if (dist <= radius) {
            fragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
            doSample = false;
            break;
        } else if (dist <= radius + 1.0) {
            fragColor = vec4(1);
            doSample = false;
        } else if (dist <= deformRadius) {lensing
            float distToEdge = deformRadius - dist;
            pos += distToEdge * normalize(deltaPos) / screenSize;
        }
    }

    if (doSample)
        fragColor = texture(u_texture, pos);
}
```

In this specific case, "count" is 1.
Is this just an intrinsic property of GLSL? Or is there some fix to it – the highest value of "count" would be 4, so I could expand it out and not use a for loop, but I feel like that isn't a very good solution.
So, does anyone know why this is happening and/or a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [GLSL ES 3.0 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.3.pdf), page 140, "12.30 Dynamic Indexing":

> For GLSL ES 1.00, support of dynamic indexing of arrays, vectors and matrices was not mandated because it was not directly supported by some implementations. Software solutions (via program transforms) exist for a subset of cases but lead to poor performance.

Note that OpenGL ES 3.0 is still not supported by all devices. Around [50% of all Android devices](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) support it at this moment. The actual implementation of the driver/compiler might not yet be as optimized though. So the actual result and performance of your code is likely to vary from device to device.

Try to avoid using dynamic branches and loops (it wouldn't even compile for GLSL ES below 3.0). If you know that your loop is at maximum 4 times executed, then using a macro to define that value:

```
#define COUNT 4
...
uniform BlackHole blackHole[COUNT];
...
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
```

If you then only need to have it loop 2 or 3 times while you compiled it for 4 times, then just put in values in the remaining items so that it will result as if those items weren't there (e.g. set the radius to zero). This is also how the [libgdx default shader](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/default.vertex.glsl) works.

The same goes for branching in your shader. You have quite some `if` and `else` in your code. Try to remove those. I havent looked at your code in depth, but it looks like you could modify it to using e.g. a `smoothstep` instead of branching.

A general tip: use a shader editor that shows, in realtime, the impact of the code that you write. For example the [PowerVR shader editor](https://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/tools/pvrshadereditor/) or the [Adreno shader editor](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/adreno-gpu-sdk/tools). This will help you a lot.

Comment: Good answer. Do you think it would suffice having an additional evaluation in the for loop, ie 'i<count && i<max_count' ?

Comment: no, that won't help. see also page 108 and further of https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf.

Comment: So I tried what you recommended, but it made it even slower – and I even tried removing the #version 330 es and letting it go to the default version for a LibGDX shader (which I think is OpenGL 2, but I'm not sure if it is) and that still didn't help.

Comment: Uh, neither. Just using the android device.

Comment: Then you probably did something wrong while modifying the shader. As said, Make sure to use an editor that shows in realtime the impact of the code that you write.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening. So I got it to work, but now I have a super strange bug. It works on my computer, it works on ShaderToy, it works with `#version 300 es` BUT with `precision highp float`s only. And it doesn't work on the android device without `#version 300 es`. And if I do make it version 300 es, the frame rate drops again.
Whenever the `deformRadius` goes to above ~255, the entire background starts zooming in and the whole screen just goes crazy. I've spent hours trying different things, and I just cannot figure this out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, so it seems that when the float precision is anything less than highp, it works; but the FPS then drops again. The only thing that I can think of that will fix this is just to make everything bigger and clamp the zoom so that it can't zoom after a certain point. I'm going to try this and if it works, then awesome. Otherwise, I have no idea what I'm going to do.

Comment: K. Wow. It didn't work. Even if I scale everything up by 10, including the black hole, there are still apparently 'precision' errors and it's just not working. I am truly stumped. Should I just make an entirely separate question for this?

Comment: Yes, that's beyond the scope of this question. Btw, never assume.